# Fill color and outline color with the same value

Tags: qgis, symbology, color

I made a categorized symbology on a shapefile, but the color value of outline (stroke color) is different than the color of fill color option. How can I ensure that both colors are the same for fill color and outline color using categorized symbology?
See an example below.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can use Data defined override.

Before categorizing click on change symbol, then choose `data defined override` for Stroke color and enter the expression `@symbol_color`.

Note that this will not be visible in your legend. You can just use a 100% transparent color to make the legend look like your polygons as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

However, in my personal eyes it would make more sense to use `No Pen` as `Stroke Style`.